# When UINavigationController is modally presented via Storyboards, it's rootViewController has no connection to it

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

My storyboard looks like this:
[image]

The first part works prefect, the problem is that when I use the "Test Modal" button to modally show the second NavigationController, that is correctly set up to have a rootViewController - the connection is not being made.

Meaning, I *know* the UINavigationController is there (with querying all controllers starting from the UIWindow's rootViewController), and my controller is also loaded, but navigationController is nil, parentViewController is nil - there's no way I could access the UINavigationController (and thus no way to customize the top toolbar)

If I check the "Is Initial View Controller" on the second UINavigationController, it works (but obviously that's not what I want). I believe this might be a UIKit bug. Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Hi, I'm an iOS beginner, but I responded to you on Twitter, because it sounded like something I do in my app. I checked your use case and you're right, the second Navigation Controller navigationController is null. But I think that's on purpose, because it's itself a navigation controller. If it had its navigationController, it would mean that it's contained in another navigation controller and thus had two toolbars.

Comment: But in my replication of the use case, self.navigationBar is there and ready for customization.

Comment: When I push a UINavigationController, i push it's rootViewController, and that is just being wrapped around. So of course I try accessing navigationController in my viewController, not in the UINavigationController.

Comment: self.navigationController in the red one is correctly set to the green one in my replication: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/115935/viewcontroller.png

Comment: I replicated the use case on my machine and uploaded the project: https://t.co/V1qv33z. When I enter the modal navigation controller, it logs correctly „<SecondNavigationController: 0xc843b10>“.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally found this one out.

I WASN'T CALLING `[super initWithCoder:decoder]` in my init. This left some UIViewController variables uninitialized. After changing that it works like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

Did implement your prepareForSegue method correctly?
This is how I implement my prepareForSegue method in my apps.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"yourConnectionName"]) {
UINavigationController *navController = segue.destinationController;
YourViewControllerClass *controller = (YourViewControllerClass *)navController.topViewController;
controller.delegate = self;
}
}
```

Comment: I don't have a delegate, so prepareForSegue should not be necessary at all. And it works, just not modally.

Comment: is the property "root view controller" set to new "View Controller" and the property "modal" to your button "Test Modal". Check that in connections inspector for your navigation controller.

Comment: Yes. I suspect it's most likely something in my controller. I've submitted a DTS to Apple.

Comment: ok strange error.
Please post your solution, if there is one.